# setting a tcl/tk library path inside a snap package

Tags: snap, tcl

After making and installing a  snap package  of tcl/tk, tcl complains it cant find  init.tcl in a series of libraries. This has been documented many times  with windows, python and tkinter, and a virt environment. This is Linux though. From what I gather so far,  tcl just needs  me to export the tcl and tk library paths that contain this file. side note- that file is  there and in most of the  paths listed. It just doesn't know it.

Looking at the  snap demo  https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/your-first-snap/

I think I need to create a script, set the library paths then launch either tcl or tk. Much like the glue used in the example. these are early days and documentation is lacking but I think I am close.

my question:
Anyone know how to set the  library paths  inside a snap? I don't mean set it in the terminal because that will only set a path on my  actual system and not for anyone  using this snap on their computer. If anything  is needed to answer this let me know. I am at work and  cant access my files currently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for anyone wanting to try this. Tcl was complaining about not finding `init.tcl` and wish wasnt even starting up. I tried every way to export the path the file was in with no luck. I noticed when generating a snap package, a wrapper is generated for each exposed binary. in this package I created 2 binaries- `tclsh` and `wish`. With no luck exporting I copied the  wrapper files to where the `snapcraft.yaml` file is because  cleaning the system would kill all the previous files generated. I added the following to each wrapper

`export TCL_LIBRARY=$SNAP/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6:$TCL_LIBRARY:$TK_LIBRARY
export TK_LIBRARY=$SNAP/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6:$TK_LIBRARY:$TCL_LIBRARY`

Then I edited the `apps:` section to reflect the use of wrappers, not direct binary calls.

`apps:
  tclsh:
    command: tclsh.wrapper #used to be just tclsh without the benefit of a wrapper with exports in it
    plugs: [home, unity7, network, x11]
  wish:
    command: wish.wrapper # same as above
    plugs: [home, unity7, network, x11]`

Finally in my `glue` section I included those wrappers

`glue:

   plugin: copy
   files:
     tclsh.wrapper: usr/bin/tclsh.wrapper
     wish.wrapper: usr/bin/wish.wrapper`

made the snap package and installed it. Both `tclsh` and `wish` work as expected with no complaints.

Tthe execute command for `tclsh` is `tcl.tclsh` and for `wish` it is `tcl.wish`.